# check if changes were made, before duplication the object (mvc 3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

If someone edits some object - I want to doplicate it, not to change it, but if there is not any change - there is no reason to duplicate it.

I want to do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateObj(Obj obj)
{
    if(check if there are changes)
    {
       db.ObjBaseSet.AddObject(obj);
       db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return view("index");
}
```

How can I do this?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use EntityState enumeration to check whether Entity object is modified or not.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate.aspx

Comment: I tried to do this: `if(obj.EntityState == EntityState.Modified)` But it is always false.